# SSRS - Unwanted spaces after rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to develope a SSRS report. But, facing issues with the formatting. It automatically leaves empty spaces based on the height of the left side field as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

Please help me to overcome this issue!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please edit question to show your report design.

Comment: Put the stuff on the left in one rectangle and the stuff on the right in another rectangle. The rectangle will grow with multiple contacts and the Address will be pushed down but it won't push anything outside the rectangle.

Comment: @HannoverFist Followed your answer. Its working! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by having separate rectangle for both side set of fields.

Credits to @HannoverFist for his comment -

Put the stuff on the left in one rectangle and the stuff on the right in another rectangle. The rectangle will grow with multiple contacts and the Address will be pushed down but it won't push anything outside the rectangle